# JQuery Themeroller Problem Loading

Tags: jquery, themeroller

I'm having trouble loading the 'tabs' and 'accordian' of the theme for this themeroller jquery plugin.  It appears the CSS is being loaded, but not the JS.  I triple-checked the JS, and its a correct filepath, so not sure why it's not being marked up.. Any suggestions?  Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>

        <!-- LOAD JQUERY THEME CSS -->
        <link type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <style type="text/css">
        ul#icons {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
        ul#icons li {margin: 2px; position: relative; padding: 4px 0; cursor: pointer; float: left;  list-style: none;}
        ul#icons span.ui-icon {float: left; margin: 0 4px;}
        </style>    


    <!-- LOAD JQUERY -->
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- LOAD JQUERY THEME JS -->
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


    <!--INITIALIZE THEME-->
    <script language="text/javascript">
     $(function(){
     // Tabs
        $('#tabs').tabs();

     // Accordion
        $("#accordion").accordion({ header: "h3" });

    });
    </script>




</head>

<body>

    <!-- Tabs -->

    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">First</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">Second</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-3">Third</a></li>

        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
        <div id="tabs-2">Phasellus mattis tincidunt nibh. Cras orci urna, blandit id, pretium vel, aliquet ornare, felis. Maecenas scelerisque sem non nisl. Fusce sed lorem in enim dictum bibendum.</div>
        <div id="tabs-3">Nam dui erat, auctor a, dignissim quis, sollicitudin eu, felis. Pellentesque nisi urna, interdum eget, sagittis et, consequat vestibulum, lacus. Mauris porttitor ullamcorper augue.</div>
    </div>


    <!-- Accordian -->

    <div id="accordion">
        <div>

            <h3><a href="#">First</a></h3>
            <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h3><a href="#">Second</a></h3>
            <div>Phasellus mattis tincidunt nibh.</div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <h3><a href="#">Third</a></h3>
            <div>Nam dui erat, auctor a, dignissim quis.</div>
        </div>
    </div>

   <!-- Theme CSS Loads fine -->

    <ul id="icons" class="ui-widget ui-helper-clearfix">
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-refresh"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-refresh"></span></li>

    </ul>



    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: nevermind, the initialise script was wrong language.. supposed to be just 'javascript' i put 'text/javascript'  ignore question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to initialize the tabs as well. The theme is loaded and everything is swell, but you're missing:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){var $tabs = $('#tabs').tabs();})
</script>
```

Correct example: http://jsfiddle.net/RCKND/